# Parse Query Results Not Appending to New Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cocoa, parse-platform

I'm using Swift and I'm trying to append a Parse Query's results to an array, however, the array only shows the appended value when it's printed within the query's for loop. When I try printing the array outside of the loop before the method's return, I get an empty array. How can I get the array with the appended value to show outside of the for loop?

```
class Task {   

    func all() -> Array<String> {
        var taskArray = Array<String>()
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Task")
        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() // this will now be nil
        let userId = currentUser?.objectId
        query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: currentUser!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) tasks.")

                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
//                        println(object.objectId)
                        let title = object["title"]! as! String
                        taskArray.append(title)
                        println("Array: \(taskArray)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
        println("Outside query array: \(taskArray)")


        return taskArray
    }
}
```

It looks like the outside query is being called before the query or something along the lines of that. Debug console:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the `println("Outside query array: \(taskArray)")` is called before `println("Array: \(taskArray)")` and there is a simple explanation to this.

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous method, which means that it starts another thread and works on this one. This means that the moment you call `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, then it continues directly to `println("Outside query array: \(taskArray)")`.

---

Now, it is possible to download stuff from Parse synchronously (so it will not skip directly to `println("Outside query array: \(taskArray)")`), but I will not recommend you to do this.

Instead I will recommend that you implement a closure which is called when the download is finished. Something similar to the following (PS, it's been written in Swift 2):

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ParseFun
//
//  Created by Stefan Veis Pennerup on 21/09/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Kumuluzz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        all { (tasks) -> Void in
            print("The downloaded tasks are: \(tasks)")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Download methods

    func all(completionHandler: ([String])->Void) {
        // Creates the query
        var taskArray = Array<String>()
        let query = PFQuery(className:"Task")
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() // this will now be nil
        query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: currentUser!)

        // Starts the download
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) tasks.")

                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        let title = object["title"]! as! String
                        taskArray.append(title)
                        print("Array: \(taskArray)")
                    }
                }

                completionHandler(taskArray)

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```